# All Google Cloud Functions fail to deploy

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I have two projects in Google Cloud, both using Firebase.  In Firebase I'm adding the Trigger Email extension that needs to deploy a Google Function.  In one project it succeeds and the other fails.  I can't seem to deploy ANY function that I write, even the simplest example.

Below is what I'm getting with one of my deploy attempts.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

`{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "status": {
      "code": 13,
      "message": "Function deployment failed due to a health check failure. This usually indicates that your code was built successfully but failed during a test execution. Examine the logs to determine the cause. Try deploying again in a few minutes if it appears to be transient."
    },
    "authenticationInfo": {
      "principalEmail": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "serviceName": "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction",
    "resourceName": "projects/wod-rewards/locations/us-central1/functions/ext-firestore-send-email-processQueue"
  },
  "insertId": "-xxxxxxxxx",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_function",
    "labels": {
      "function_name": "ext-firestore-send-email-processQueue",
      "project_id": "xxxxxxxx",
      "region": "us-central1"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-02-14T20:39:25.365473Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/wod-rewards/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity",
  "operation": {
    "id": "operations/xxxxxxxx",
    "producer": "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com",
    "last": true
  },
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-02-14T20:39:25.706517396Z"
}`

Answer (score 0):

You should check your logs for Cloud Functions in Google Cloud, might be possible that you ahve a configuration issue with your billing settings blocking you from excecute some tasks from your functions

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The code above is what appears in the Log for the Cloud Function.  Perhaps there's another log I need to look at?  Otherwise, the "code" above is what I found in the log when the deploy failed.

Comment: Yes, go to  [Cloud Console](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/) then go to Logging, select Cloud Functions and you will see more errors related to your Cloud Functions, then you can check if there is any issue with your billing settings

Comment: I went to Logging and see this.  However, I do have a billing account set up and assigned to both my projects.  One was successful deploying the function, the other one was not.

Comment: {
      "code": 9,
      "message": "Cloud storage operation for gcf-upload-us-central1-5f7b873b-7580-4674-8ea5-8031410c4e02 failed as the billing account is not available"
    },
    "authenticationInfo": {
     ...... "google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.GenerateUploadUrl",
    "resourceName": "projects/wod-rewards/locations/us-central1"
  },
  
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/wod-rewards/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access",

Comment: Well this looks strange, there might be an issue with your account, at this point you should contact with [Cloud Support Billing](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing) as thay can check this issue quickly for you and help to unblock this situation.